Issue with JSON parsing in Snowflake when using dbt
I have a array of json column called params which has values such as
 [
    {"key": "abc", "value": 1},
    {"key": "def", "value": 2},
    {"key": "ghi", "value": 3}
] 

I want to convert it to {"abc":1, "def":2, "ghi":3}
I have this dbt macro to do the job
{% macro array_to_dict(ARR, KEY_FIELD_NAME, VALUE_FIELD_NAME) %}
    {% set sql_query %}
        SELECT OBJECT_AGG(
            PARSE_JSON(f.{{ VALUE_FIELD_NAME }}):{{ KEY_FIELD_NAME }},
            PARSE_JSON(f.{{ VALUE_FIELD_NAME }}):{{ VALUE_FIELD_NAME }}
        ) AS json_object
        FROM LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT => PARSE_JSON('{{ ARR }}')) AS f
        GROUP BY f.this
    {% endset %}
    {{ log("SQL to run: " ~ sql_query, info=True) }}
    {{ return(run_query(sql_query)) }}
{% endmacro %}


I am calling this macro from model
select
    id,
    {{ array_to_dict('params', 'key', 'value') }} as _params
from
    test

I am getting the error
100069 (22P02): Error parsing JSON: unknown keyword "params", pos 7

how can I make it work?

I'd start looking into how does that SQL compiles, with dbt compile -s <my_model>

@AleixCC gives the same error while compilation

Why do you have quotes around {{ ARR }}? You're parsing the string 'params' not a column.

to have this fully functional on multiple cases, I'd do the following:

create a macro that builds a CTE
that CTE will have an ID to later join, and will handle the flatten
then, you can call that macro at the top of your models, and only need to join later by the ID

-- macros/array_to_dict_cte.sql

{% macro array_to_dict_cte(
    id, 
    model_name, 
    field_name, 
    key_field_name, 
    value_field_name
  )
%}

with array_to_dict_cte as (
  select
    {{ id }},
    object_agg(
      parse_json(j.value):{{ key_field_name }}::varchar, 
      parse_json(j.value):{{ value_field_name }}::number
    ) as transformed_json
  from {{ ref('model_name') }},
  lateral flatten(input => {{ field_name }}) as j
),

{% endmacro %}

From here, you would just need your model to do the following:
-- your_model.sql

{{ array_to_dict_cte('id', '<your_model_name>', 'params', 'key', 'value') }}

joined as (
  select
    <your_model_name>.id,
    array_to_dict_cte.transformed_json
  from {{ ref('<your_model_name>') }}
  left join array_to_dict_cte on <your_model_name>.id = array_to_dict_cte.id
)

select * from joined

Give it a try and let me know! Haven't tested this specific use case, but we use a similar approach in our dbt project for an almost identical challenge.
